# How can I make my loader fade out and display my website correctly?

Tags: html, css

basically, I have created a loader for my website. However, I want my loader to fade out and display my website. Right now, my loader is just on the website. How can I make my loader fade out with its container? I would like my loader to fade out like this: http://manangwebsite.rf.gd/?i=1 Here is my code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```css
    body{
        background: #333;
    }
    
    .container{
        position: absolute;
        height: 400px;
        width: 200px;
        top: 20%;
        left: 43%;
    }
    
    .loader{
        height: 95%;
        width: 95%;
        margin: 2.5%;
        border-top: 3px solid #40e0d0;
        border-bottom: 3px solid darkgreen;
        border-radius: 50%;
        animation: 30s rotate linear infinite;
    }
    
    @keyframes rotate{
        0%{
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100%{
            transform: rotate(810deg);
        }
    }
    
    body{
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .wrapper{
        width: 1170px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    header{
        height: 100px;
        background: #262626;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 12;
        position: fixed;
    }
    
    .logo{
        width: 30%;
        float: left;
        line-height: 100px;
    }
    
    .logo a{
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: bignoodletitling;
        color: #fff;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
    }
    
    nav{
        float: right;
        line-height: 100px;
    }
    
    nav a{
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: bignoodletitling;
        letter-spacing: 4px;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 0 10px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    .banner-area{
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 100px;
        background-image: url(mountain.jpg);
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    
    .banner-area h2{
        padding-top: 8%;
        font-size: 70px;
        font-family: poppins;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    .content-area{
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        top: 450px;
        background: #ddd;
        height: 1500px;
    }
    
    .content-area h2{
        font-family: bignoodletitling;
        letter-spacing: 4px;
        padding-top: 30px;
        font-size: 40px;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .content-area p{
        padding: 2%;
        font-family: bignoodletitling;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="loader">
              <div class="loader">
                <div class="loader">
                  <div class="loader">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> 
          
          <div class = "box-area">
            <header>
               <div class="wrapper">
                   <div class="logo">
                       <a href="#">Front Page</a>
                   </div>
                   <nav>
                       <a href="#">Home</a>
                       <a href="#">About</a>
                       <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                       <a href="#">Blog</a>
                       <a href="#">Contact</a>
                   </nav>
               </div>
            </header>
            <div class="banner-area">
            </div>
            <div class="content-area">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <h2>Test</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, aspernatur eos, fugit optio vero ratione dolore consequatur suscipit quo nesciunt eveniet ipsam! Necessitatibus, facilis odio? Cupiditate molestiae expedita voluptas atque!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
           </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on load in jQuery is solution - It can see the actual time spent when uploading its text and images content

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.load').delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

```css
body{
    background: #333;
}

.container{
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    top: 20%;
    left: 43%;
}

.loader{
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 2.5%;
    border-top: 3px solid #40e0d0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid darkgreen;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: 30s rotate linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate{
    0%{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform: rotate(810deg);
    }
}

body{
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header{
    height: 100px;
    background: #262626;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 12;
    position: fixed;
}

.logo{
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    line-height: 100px;
}

.logo a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: bignoodletitling;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

nav{
    float: right;
    line-height: 100px;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: bignoodletitling;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.banner-area{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    background-image: url(mountain.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

.banner-area h2{
    padding-top: 8%;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: poppins;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
}

.content-area{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 450px;
    background: #ddd;
    height: 1500px;
}

.content-area h2{
    font-family: bignoodletitling;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 0;
}

.content-area p{
    padding: 2%;
    font-family: bignoodletitling;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.load {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 99;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="load">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="loader">
          <div class="loader">
            <div class="loader">
              <div class="loader">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
   </div>
      <div class = "box-area">
        <header>
           <div class="wrapper">
               <div class="logo">
                   <a href="#">Front Page</a>
               </div>
               <nav>
                   <a href="#">Home</a>
                   <a href="#">About</a>
                   <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                   <a href="#">Blog</a>
                   <a href="#">Contact</a>
               </nav>
           </div>
        </header>
        <div class="banner-area">
        </div>
        <div class="content-area">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h2>Test</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, aspernatur eos, fugit optio vero ratione dolore consequatur suscipit quo nesciunt eveniet ipsam! Necessitatibus, facilis odio? Cupiditate molestiae expedita voluptas atque!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this type of preloader by adding some CSS. By the javascript setTimeout function you can hide the preloader

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.load').delay(1500).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

```css
body{
    background: #333;
}

.container{
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    top: 20%;
    left: 43%;
}

.loader{
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 2.5%;
    border-top: 3px solid #40e0d0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid darkgreen;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: 30s rotate linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate{
    0%{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform: rotate(810deg);
    }
}

body{
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header{
    height: 100px;
    background: #262626;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 12;
    position: fixed;
}

.logo{
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    line-height: 100px;
}

.logo a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: bignoodletitling;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

nav{
    float: right;
    line-height: 100px;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: bignoodletitling;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.banner-area{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    background-image: url(mountain.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

.banner-area h2{
    padding-top: 8%;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: poppins;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
}

.content-area{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 450px;
    background: #ddd;
    height: 1500px;
}

.content-area h2{
    font-family: bignoodletitling;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 0;
}

.content-area p{
    padding: 2%;
    font-family: bignoodletitling;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.load {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 99;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="load">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="loader">
          <div class="loader">
            <div class="loader">
              <div class="loader">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
   </div>
      <div class = "box-area">
        <header>
           <div class="wrapper">
               <div class="logo">
                   <a href="#">Front Page</a>
               </div>
               <nav>
                   <a href="#">Home</a>
                   <a href="#">About</a>
                   <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                   <a href="#">Blog</a>
                   <a href="#">Contact</a>
               </nav>
           </div>
        </header>
        <div class="banner-area">
        </div>
        <div class="content-area">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h2>Test</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, aspernatur eos, fugit optio vero ratione dolore consequatur suscipit quo nesciunt eveniet ipsam! Necessitatibus, facilis odio? Cupiditate molestiae expedita voluptas atque!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: I would like to substitute my loader in for the one in the website though. Will this work if I put my loader code in instead of the website I linked?

Comment: I don't understand what are you talking about, you can just copy-paste my code to your workbanch

Comment: @RaymondNelson Yes, I think it should (I'm not sure since I'm not the answer author, though)

Comment: @RaymondNelson you can test it by Run Code snippet

Comment: If you Run Code snippet my original (the one you edited) I want that loader to fade away. Not the green one. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: oh yeah I understand,ok just wait

Comment: just check my new answer